# Wrap php generated content in a div wrap

Tags: php, wordpress, wrapper, advanced-custom-fields

I am using a php code snippet (below) from Advanced Custom Fields with Wordpress. Rather than statically placing the div around the php, I would like the php to generate the div only if there is content for the php the generate. How would I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Here is the link to Advanced Custom Fields
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/oembed/

```
<div class="embed-container">
    <?php the_field('oembed'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Easiest is if you modify the function `the_field()` such that it outputs the `div` container itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use recommended syntax to check if the field has a value and display it.

```
<?php 

// Check if the field has a value

if ( get_field('oembed') ): ?>

<div class="embed-container">
    <?php the_field('oembed'); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Here's [some further info from ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/hiding-empty-fields/) if you want to extend it to check and show multiple fields.

Answer (score 0):

This would be an easy approach:

```
<?php
$output = trim(the_field('oembed'));
if (!empty($output)) {
  echo "<div class=\"embed-container\">
    $output
  </div>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it broke the site. I also tried closing the php tag (it was left open in your suggestion) and that didn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, indeed there was an obvious syntax error in it since I just copied your code without fully adapting it. Should be fixed now.

Comment: There we go! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, sorry. upon further examination, your code snippet fixed the site but didn't wrap the content in the div.

Comment: Looks like your function `the_field()` directly outputs the content instead of returning it. If so you could use output buffering as a solution, but that is quite a huge effort.

Answer (score 0):

The first line checks if the field exists and is not null, and if so, removes whitespace. Then the third line checks if the trimmed field isn't empty, and if not adds  tags around it, according to the format in line 2:

```
<?php

   $field = isset(the_field("oembed")) ? trim(the_field('oembed')) : "";
   $format = "<div>%s</div>";
   echo !empty($field) ? sprintf($format, $field) : ""; 

?>
```